# Enable authentication in ASP.NET web service

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, web-services

How do I configure .NET web service to require all consumers to supply credentials, then verify their validity against database table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using class ASP.NET ASMX Web Services, I would suggest you download Microsoft's [Web Service Enhancements 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en). That will enable you to properly support WS-Security.

You could also use custom SOAP Headers, but that method doesn't conform to WS-Security standards and could cause interoperability problems if you're consuming the services from a non-.NET platform.

If you're using WCF, you just need to configure your binding to use the proper type of security. Take a look at [Bindings and Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172.aspx). It's a broad overview and you'll have to dig a little deeper to get the specifics for your type of binding.

Comment: Isn't WSE 3.0 just for .NET 2.0?

Comment: @Chris Diver - They may be supported, but they don't conform to the standard for Web Service Interop so it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Justin - but they conform to the standard of SOAP web services.

Comment: @Sphynx - WSE 3.0 is only supported for Visual Studio 2005, correct. If you're using Visual Studio 2008, Microsoft advocates migrating to WCF if you need the added functionality.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I've switched to WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.

Have a look at the SoapHeader class for one - there is a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77hkfhh8%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if you could do worse than read:

http://progtutorials.tripod.com/Authen.htm

"Forms Authentication".